# Navigation test works on the emulator but not on the real device

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito, android-espresso, android-testing

I am trying to test navigation with Espresso and Mockito. I'm using real device (Android 12) to see the results. With below code testing it gets stuck on the loading and not complete the test even after 10 minutes of waiting.

Then i wanted to run it with emulator (Pixel_API_32) and it worked. Do i miss something like some options or just it will not suppose to work on real device?

I searched for answer found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61800813/4058604) but didn't help. Can someone enlighten me?

```
@MediumTest
@HiltAndroidTest
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class ShoppingFragmentTest {

    @get:Rule
    var hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        hiltRule.inject()
    }

    @Test
    fun clickAddShoppingItemButton_navigateToAddShoppingItemFragment() {
        val navController = Mockito.mock(NavController::class.java)
        launchFragmentInHiltContainer<ShoppingFragment> {
            Navigation.setViewNavController(requireView(), navController)
        }

        Espresso.onView(withId(R.id.fabAddShoppingItem)).perform(click())

        Mockito.verify(navController).navigate(
            ShoppingFragmentDirections.actionShoppingFragmentToAddShoppingItemFragment()
        )
    }
}
```

[image: On real Device]

[image: On the Emulator]

Comment: have you tried disabling the animations on your device ?

Comment: With your comment i tried but still no luck.